# Image automaticly proportionally resize to remaining size of parent, both landscape and portrait

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, autoresize

I'm building a web app and this current screen I'm working on contains one image per screen. This image should be completely visible in the remaining space (screen minus navigation bar). When the device is either tilted portrait or landscape, the image itself should automatically adjust to the remaining space.

Let's say that this is the markup

```
<body>
   <div class="nav">
      // this is 64px height
   </div>
   <div class="focusCam"> // contains 15px padding inside
      <img>
   </div>
</body>
```

I've tried various methods with either or even both CSS and jQuery, but I keep failing.

Simply using

```
.focusCam img {
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Isn't working. Because when in landscape, the bottom part of the image exceeds the screen, resulting in a scroll view.

Who can tell me a great solution? Thanks.

*p.s. I've recently asked a look-a-like question, but this one is completely different. Don't confuse/link them.*

Comment: set `focusCam` css so it is contained in viewport, then image will adjust to it's parent

Comment: ..huh? Could you explain a bit more? :)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with focusCam, not the `img` property.

Try something like this:

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.nav {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:64px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.focusCam {
  padding:79px 15px 15px 15px;
  height:100%;
}
```

Note the padding top which includes 64px for the nav menu and 15px of padding.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jiq9EjkOPzsTOhjWxti?p=preview) for it.